Playwright - When I do npm link, I'm not getting the playwright recognized in test project from core/dependency project
Playwright With Typescript is used in dependency project (Core, App1 etc) and My test project using the dependency project. It is working fine when do NPM install as per the test project package.json ( which contains dependencies as "core":"1.0.0", "app1": "1.0.0")
Working:
In Core Project, npm build --> npm pack   ........
In Test project,   npm install
All working fine for above approach.
For Dev environment, testers need to make chaange to Pages and tests at same time so we tried to link projects locally so I dont need to pack and install everytime.
For Dev Environment  - Test project package.json has both core and app1 dependency as  file:../Core/packages/core, file:../Core/packages/app1
In Core project, npm build --> npm link  ........
In Test project,  npm link core app1
When I do npm link, I'm not getting the playwright recognized in test project from core/dependency project. If I install playwright again  (same version) in Test project, Im getting "Playwright required second time error" error.
Core
-package.json
-packages/core
--src
---pages
--package.json
-packages/app1
--src
---pages
--package.json
Test
-package.json
-tests/e2e
--spec-app1.ts
-testdata
-env
-playwright.config.ts
